# fixing type mismatch error while parsing json in android

Tags: android, json

**the following is the try to search from server database**

```
[["30","KAB-097V","726735765","Bus\/Truck\/Lorry","Cash"],["31","KZE-053H","725940835","Bus\/Truck\/Lorry","Cash"],["32","KAG-784K","723489849","Saloon\/pick up\/any other personal car","MPESA"],["33","kab-123p","973934940","Omni Bus\/ Omni Truck","Cash"],["34","KAD-123K","484984745","Omni Bus\/ Omni Truck","Cash"]]
```

**below is my java class**

```
 public class Parser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,Integer> {
    Context c;
    String data;
    RecyclerView rv;
    ArrayList<String> plates = new ArrayList<>();

    public Parser(Context c, String data, RecyclerView rv) {
        this.c = c;
        this.data = data;
        this.rv = rv;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return this.parser();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
        super.onPostExecute(integer);
        if (integer==1){
                rv.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(c,plates));
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(c, "Unable to parse",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    private int parser(){
        try {
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(data);
            JSONObject jo=null;
            plates.clear();
            for (int i=0; i<ja.length();i++){
                jo =ja.getJSONObject(i);
                String number = jo.getString("payment");
                plates.add(number);
            }
            return 1;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**when i run the class it gives the above toast of *unable to parse* and gives following error**

```
 org.json.JSONException: Value ["27","KAC-123","7585765","Saloon car","MPESA"] at 0 of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
```

03-01 04:08:51.166 2929-19534/com.codek.kipz.parkingverication W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:525)
03-01 04:08:51.166 2929-19534/com.codek.kipz.parkingverication W/System.err:     at com.codek.kipz.parkingverication.MySQL.Parser.parser(Parser.java:57)

Comment: Can you post the JSON as well?

Answer (score 0):

Your example json does not contain any JSONObjects. Instead it is an Array of Arrays.

```
jo =ja.getJSONObject(i);
```

Here you try to read a json *object*, but there aren't any, so it throws an exception.

Then you try to read an argument called 'payments' and use it as a plate (which seems odd on it's own). Because your json does not contain any named arguments, you will have to use the index at which it is stored in each array.

Replace your parser method with the following code

```
private int parser() {
    try {
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(data);
        plates.clear();

        for(int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
            JSONArray array = ja.getJSONArray(i);
            // The plate appears to be stored as the second item in each array
            String plate = array.getString(1);
            plates.add(plate);
        }
        return 1;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
}
```